# single select vs multiple selects using limit and offset

Tags: sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database, entity-framework

Working on a fairly high volume site. There are some tables example - the customers table which gets hit a lot.

**The problem**

We are writing a piece of code that selects a bunch of customers and sends out mailers etc (nothing mission critical). These selects often result in about 20000 records. We obviously do not want the regular hits to the customer table being blocked by these select statements.

We went down the route of making these reads readUncommitted since the operations on the data are absolutely not mission critical.

However, instead of making these massive selects if in code we make a select with a limit and an offset and keep looping would that cause less locks on the db.

**In other words - would 20 select statements each retrieving 1000 records be more desirable than 1 select statement retrieving 20000 records in terms of reducing locking etc.**

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

20k records is not that many. Are you `SELECTing` other data from other tables as part of your mailout which is slowing things down? Are you keeping your transaction open longer than you need?

Otherwise, can you use one of the opimistic concurrency [isolation levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx): `Snapshot` or `Read Committed Snapshot`? They should allow you to read without blocking.

Comment: Nope. There are other transactions that happen on the customers table from which the 20k records are selected. I do not want this select to block these transactions as they are more important.

Comment: we are on SQL Azure. The isolation level Read Committed snapshot seems to be a database level setting. We have several transactions running as Serializable. Would this setting affect those transactions?

Comment: According to [TechNet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/handling-transactions-in-sql-azure.aspx) Read Committed Snapshot and Snapshot isolation levels are enabled by default in Azure; query `sys.databases` to confirm. Both those isolation levels allow selects to read data even if records are locked by another transaction (even `Serializable` ones). Your reader will see an older version of the data.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, first thing, I need to pick at this a little bit:

> We went down the route of making these reads readUncommitted since the
>   operations on the data are absolutely not mission critical.

Using `READ UNCOMMITTED`/`NOLOCK` should only be considered when the ***accuracy of the results*** is not critical, because that's what the transaction isolation level affects. I understand that the operation is not *mission-critical*, but that should not be the driver behind selecting a less restrictive isolation level.

> In other words - would 20 select statements each retrieving 1000
>   records be more desirable than 1 select statement retrieving 20000
>   records in terms of reducing locking etc.

If you continue to use `READ UNCOMMITTED`, the *locking* overhead will be the same between the two methods (i.e., no locks will be taken). However, running multiple statements instead of one can affect other things, such as query compilation (which uses CPU), network chattiness, and the complexity of your application. In this case, I think the operation of sending a mailer would be relatively infrequent (I could be wrong), so the latter factor may be the most important to consider.

If you choose to switch back to a higher isolation level for accuracy reasons, that is an entirely different ball game in terms of locking.

Answer (score 1):

> You should go for proper indexing of records as in SQL server 20000
>   records is not much more ,you can easily pick in a single select
>   statement. If possible in single statement then why should go for
>   multiple.
>
> So better solution is that if records are not retrieved fast then
>   create the indexes as per the need to optimize your select statement.